# styling overrides native focus rectangle android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

For my project i have an a custom EditText view that extends EditText.  I am also applying a styling to it.. but it seems when i apply the style the native RECTANGLE showing that the field is focused goes away..  my style looks like this:

```
<style name="edit_text">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:cursorVisible">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/text_view_bg</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>

    </style>    
<style name="large_edit_text" parent="@style/edit_text">
            <item name="android:layout_width">740dip</item>
            <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
            <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
        </style>
```

this shows the focus rectangle:

```
<medicalforms.form.FormEditText
        android:layout_width="580dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        formview:form_id="first_name"

        formview:form_action="@string/action_property_change"
        />
```

and this does not:

```
<medicalforms.form.FormEditText
        style="@style/large_edit_text"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        formview:form_id="first_name"

        formview:form_action="@string/action_property_change"
        />
```

can someone tell me why?  i want to keep the native rectangle cue that the field is focused.. but use my styling

Comment: What's `parent="@style/edit_text"`?

Comment: its @style.large_edit_text and it is the style being applied see the first node of code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there it is: `<item name="android:background">@drawable/text_view_bg</item>` If that drawable is just a plain image, then you won't have the focused, pressed or selected states. If you look at the drawable that is used for the default EditText, it's composed of four (or five?) different images for the states.

Comment: thanks yeah.. i realized that right before you posted.. thank you though very much.. where can i find the drawable used for native fields?

Comment: If you're using the default EditText (i.e. non-holo), there's an XML in the sdk's folder: `/platforms/android-?/data/res/drawable/edit_text.xml`. Then that XML points to the different images in the `/data/res/drawable-hdpi/` folder. There's an XML and images for the holo themes.